# Get pedometer info error in samsung gear 2

Tags: tizen

For this code:

```
window.tizen.humanactivitymonitor.start(
        "PEDOMETER",
        function onSuccess(pedometerInfo) {
            console.log("successful");
        }
    );
```

Getting this error:

> NotSupportedError: pedometer not supported

the API of pedometer said that "the given type is not supported on a device", but I tried running on smartwatch 2.3. I'm using tizen SDK 2.4 and emulator smartwatch 2.3

Answer (score 1):

"but I tried running on smartwatch 2.3. I'm using tizen SDK 2.4 and emulator smartwatch 2.3"

Did you try on a device or on emulator?

If you try on emulator it will not work.
On device it does.

Here's a tutorial:

http://denvycom.com/blog/accessing-sensor-data-on-samsung-gear-2/

https://github.com/chuvidi2003/SimpleSensor

Comment: The emulator cannot always provide the right feel/output you would get from a real device, so it is better to test on a real gear s2.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting someone on the web:
Gear S software platform is Wearable 1.0(Tizen 2.2) based, but pedometer API you implemented is for new SDK Tizen 2.3 that works on Gear S2.
Tizen 2.2 => webapis.motion.setAccumulativePedometerListener(onchangedCB);
Tizen 2.3 => tizen.humanactivitymonitor.setAccumulativePedometerListener(onchangedCB);
also need to check if required privilege is defined on your app : "http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/healthinfo"

Same goes for heart rate.